# No output from FOR loop over command

Tags: git, cmd.exe

I've got some files I just committed in my git repo:

> C:\core\guidewire\Release\5.3_MT1\ClaimCenter>git diff --name-only head^^
>   ClaimCenter/modules/configuration/config/web/pcf/TabBar.pcf
>   ClaimCenter/modules/configuration/config/web/pcf/team/user/TeamUserClaims.pcf
>   ClaimCenter/modules/configuration/gsrc/citizens/cc/pcf_gs/team/TeamTabLastUser.gs

Now I want to capture the paths and do something else with them, but the `git diff` command doesn't produce(?) any lines for `FOR /F` to iterate over:

> C:\core\guidewire\Release\5.3_MT1\ClaimCenter>for /f %p in ('git diff --name-only head^^') do @( echo %p )
>
> C:\core\guidewire\Release\5.3_MT1\ClaimCenter>

**What's going on here?** At first I expected it was some mistake in my syntax, but diffing against other targets works inside the for-loop. For example, "master^^" proves that it's not just the escape character playing havoc:

> C:\core\guidewire\Release\5.3_MT1\ClaimCenter>for /f %p in ('git diff --name-only master^^') do @( echo %p )
>   ClaimCenter/modules/configuration/config/rules/Reopened/ClaimReopened_dir/CRO05000ApplyCustomReopenRule_dir/CRO05010AssignToOriginalAdjuster.gr
>   ClaimCenter/modules/configuration/config/rules/Reopened/ClaimReopened_dir/CRO05000ApplyCustomReopenRule_dir/CRO05030DefaultAssignment.gr
>   ClaimCenter/modules/configuration/config/web/pcf/TabBar.pcf
>   ClaimCenter/modules/configuration/config/web/pcf/team/user/TeamUserClaims.pcf
>   ClaimCenter/modules/configuration/gsrc/citizens/cc/pcf_gs/team/TeamTabLastUser.gs

Comment: We all know CMD.EXE is *idiosyncratic* to say the least but what's extra-frustrating is how the only case I need (files changed in HEAD) is the only case I've found that doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

**Double-escape "head^" to "head^^^^"**:

> C:\core\guidewire\Release\5.3_MT1\ClaimCenter>for /f %p in ('git diff --name-only head^^^^') do @(echo %p)
>   ClaimCenter/modules/configuration/config/web/pcf/TabBar.pcf
>   ClaimCenter/modules/configuration/config/web/pcf/team/user/TeamUserClaims.pcf
>   ClaimCenter/modules/configuration/gsrc/citizens/cc/pcf_gs/team/TeamTabLastUser.gs

When CMD runs the quoted command a second round of expansion takes place so `^^` becomes `^` and then . In fact, the test case diffing against "master^^" doesn't prove anything since it ends up with no carets left. The original command line simply diffed HEAD against HEAD which of course has no files changed at all.